# Why are weights defined to be locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

My question is about why weights are defined to be locally integrable.

I am trying to understand a statement in the paper "Poincare Inequalities and Neumann problems for the $p$-Laplacian" by David Cruz-Uribe, Scott Rodney and Emily Rosta. The paper can be found on the arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03932).

Lemma 2.2 in the paper is where my question stems from. My question involves this particular statement in the proof: "since $\lambda_j^{p/2}(x) \leq \gamma(x) \in L^1_{loc}(E)$ a.e. the spaces $L^p(\lambda_j^{p/2};E)$ are complete..."

The proof that $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is a banach space translates virtually unchanged into a proof that $L^p(w;\mathbb{R})$ is a banach space for a weight $w$. It doesn't seem to need the condition that $w \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$.

I know weights are defined to be locally integrable, but is local integrability a necessary condition for a weighted Lebesgue space to be complete? Is there an example of a weight $w$ with $w \not\in L^1_{loc}(E)$ such that $L^p(w;E)$ is not complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not, it is not needed, however, it is usually added for convenience as weights appearing in the real-life scenarios are usually locally integrable and this allows for using certain separation arguments. So what is a weight really?

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $w\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative, measurable function. Note that in this setting we cannot talk about local integrability as we don't have any topology at hand.

As $w \geqslant 0$, the integral $\int_X w\, {\rm d}\mu$ exists but may be infinite. Then you may consider $L_p(w, \mu)$, which is $L_p(\nu)$ for $\nu(A) = \int_A w {\rm d}\mu$. So as such this space is complete. The moral of that story is that weighted $L_p$-spaces are still $L_p$-spaces (and as such complete) but under a different measure.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. When you say "we cannot talk about local integrability as we don't have a topology at hand", is that because without a topology, we don't have a notion of compactness?

Comment: @MichaelPenrod, exactly. Measures are a priori unrelated to topology (compactness, open sets) but they often come in pairs.